# Addressing localhost from ubuntu to windows 8 via Virtualbox

Tags: docker, ubuntu, localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm developing a simple web application with springboot in Windows 8.

When I deploy jar file into docker in Ubuntu and run the container, I can see it works on address *10.0.2.15:8082* which is a local IP address, correctly.

What I want is to connect this IP address in my Windows 8 then I will use postman to post some JSON variables etc. But I can't connect *10.0.2.15:8082* from Windows 8.

My VirtualBox adapter attached to NAT and also some rules are given:

[image: Networking Settings]

I also tried to change host and guest rules otherwise, but didnt work either.

When I run the application in Windows 8 and check it with *192.168.56.1:8082*, it gives success and also I can see the same result in Ubuntu with the same address. but can't get it to work otherwise.

[image]

I expect to connect ubuntu's localhost in my Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer;

After shutting down vm, i added second adapter as Host-only Adapter. After starting virtual machine, in terminal by entering "ifconfig" command you can see ip4 address for host-only adapter (in Windows it is Ethernet adapter Virtualbox Host-Only Network). When you try to enter that address in windows and ubuntu, it shows the result.

Also that *192.168.56.1* address is Windows Virtualbox Host-Only Network IPv4 address in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I believe NAT adapters do not allow direct connection between host and guest, you will need a second `Host-only Adapter` for that purpose.

See [this link](https://technology.amis.nl/2018/07/27/virtualbox-networking-explained/) for a nice explanation.